# Stata: saving regressions coefficients and standard errors in .dta file when there are factor variables

Tags: regression, stata, categorical-data

I would like to run several regressions and store their results in a DTA file that I could later use for analysis. My constraints are:

1. I cannot install modules (I am writing code for other people and not
   sure what modules they have installed)
2. Some of the regressors are factor variables.
3. Each regression differ only by the dependent variable, so I would like to store that in the final dataset to keep track of what regression the coefficients/variances correspond to.

I am seriously losing sanity here. I feel it's probably simple given that Stata is statistics software but `svmat` is really not cooperative. Currently what I am doing is this:

```
sysuse census, clear
generate constant = 1
capture matrix drop regsresults // erase previously existing matrix
foreach depvar in marriage divorce {

    reg `depvar' popurban i.region constant, robust noconstant  // regressions
    matrix result_matrix = e(b)\vecdiag(e(V))                   // grab coeffs and their variances in a 2xK matrix
    matrix rownames result_matrix = `depvar'_b `depvar'_v       // add rownames to the two extra rows
    matrix regsresults = nullmat(regsresults)\result_matrix     // add those results matrix to the existing ones

}
matrix list regsresults
clear 
svmat regsresults, names(col)
```

This creates for each regression: one row that stores the coefficients, one row that stores their variance using `vecdiag(e(V))`. The row names for those two rows are the dependent variable name, followed by _b for coeffs and _v for variances.

I use a manual constant because _cons is not a valid name for a variable when using `svmat`.

Of course my "solution" does not work because factor levels generate strange matrix column names which are then invalid variable names when calling `svmat`. (The error is a terse `invalid syntax`.) I'd be happy with ANY solution to overcome that problem, given my constraints. It doesn't have to use svmat, coefficients and variances can be on same line if it makes it easier, etc.

Comment: Have you tried `help postfile`? It's worth the read (including the manual entry -very important).

Comment: You can also change the matrix column names. `help svmat` has the information (the command is `matname`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming matrix columns is one option:

```
sysuse census, clear
generate constant = 1
capture matrix drop regsresults // erase previously existing matrix
foreach depvar in marriage divorce {

    reg `depvar' popurban i.region constant, robust noconstant  // regressions
    matrix result_matrix = e(b)\vecdiag(e(V))                   // grab coeffs and their variances in a 2xK matrix
    matrix rownames result_matrix = `depvar'_b `depvar'_v       // add rownames to the two extra rows
    matrix regsresults = nullmat(regsresults)\result_matrix     // add those results matrix to the existing ones

}
matrix list regsresults
matname regsresults reg1 reg2 reg3 reg4, columns(2..5) explicit

clear 
svmat regsresults, names(col)
```

For more complex *namelists* (reg1 - reg4), you can build the syntax beforehand, store in a `local`, and then use with `matname`.

### Edit

The same strategy, with some automatation. It uses *macro extended functions* for matrices. See `help extended_fcn`.

```
sysuse census, clear
generate constant = 1
capture matrix drop regsresults // erase previously existing matrix
foreach depvar in marriage divorce {

    reg `depvar' popurban i.region constant, robust noconstant  // regressions
    matrix result_matrix = e(b)\vecdiag(e(V))                   // grab coeffs and their variances in a 2xK matrix
    matrix rownames result_matrix = `depvar'_b `depvar'_v       // add rownames to the two extra rows
    matrix regsresults = nullmat(regsresults)\result_matrix     // add those results matrix to the existing ones

}

// list the matrix
matrix list regsresults

// get original column names of matrix
local names : colfullnames regsresults

// get original row names of matrix (and row count)
local rownames : rowfullnames regsresults
local c : word count `rownames'

// make original names legal variable names
local newnames
foreach name of local names {
    local newnames `newnames' `=strtoname("`name'")'
}

// rename columns of matrix
matrix colnames regsresults = `newnames'

// convert matrix to dataset
clear 
svmat regsresults, names(col)

// add matrix row names to dataset
gen rownames = ""
forvalues i = 1/`c' {
    replace rownames = "`:word `i' of `rownames''" in `i'
}

// list
order rownames
list, noobs
```

See also `ssc describe matnames`.

Comment: Thank you I will try that. Of course it's a bit more cumbersome in my actual problem because I do not know ex-ante how many dummy variables are created for the factor variables but I will probably use `levelsof` to know that.

Comment: I tried the solution you mentioned, but the problem is I need to retrieve the unique values of the factor variables. I will need to know in my dataset what value the factor dummy was taking for which coefficient.

Comment: [After your edit] Amazing, thank you so much! It keeps the value of the factor variable now! Perhaps one more question, although you've already gone out of your way, is it possible to store the matrix rownames as a variable?

Comment: Nevermind I find a way to transport row_names and readd them at the add. It's hacky but it works, will post my final code.

Comment: One way is with a loop (added to the answer). But there should be more.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, using Roberto excellent solution, this is the final code:

```
sysuse census, clear
generate constant = 1
capture matrix drop regsresults // erase previously existing matrix
replace region = region +15
foreach depvar in marriage divorce {

    reg `depvar' popurban i.region constant, robust noconstant  // regressions
    matrix result_matrix = e(b)\vecdiag(e(V))                   // grab coeffs and their variances in a 2xK matrix
    matrix rownames result_matrix = `depvar'_b `depvar'_v       // add rownames to the two extra rows
    matrix regsresults = nullmat(regsresults)\result_matrix     // add those results matrix to the existing ones

}

matrix list regsresults
local rownames : rownames regsresults           // collects row names
local colnames : colfullnames regsresults       // collects column names
local newnames                                  // clean column names
foreach name of local colnames {
    local newnames `newnames' `=strtoname("`name'")'
}
matrix colnames regsresults = `newnames'        // attribute the cleaned column names

clear 
svmat regsresults, names(col)

// add the row names as its own variable rown
gen str rown = ""
order rown, 
local i = 1
foreach rowname in `rownames' {
    replace rown = "`rowname'" if _n == `i'
    local i = `i' + 1
}
br
```