# Stata: convert a matrix to dataset without losing names

Tags: stata

This question has been asked before but the answers do not seem to apply here. I would like to make a dataset from my regression output, without losing information. Consider:

```
clear *
input str3 iso3 var1 var2 var3
GBR    10 13 15
USA    9 7 4
FRA    8 8 7
BEL    3 4 5
end

local vars var2 var3
reg var1 var2 var3
matrix A=r(table)
matrix list A

clear
xsvmat A, names(col) norestore
```

Where Stata complains about the `_cons` column. I'm not interested in this column (although I also don't understand why it is such a problem to include it) but I don't find an option to cope with this in the `xsvmat`, `svmat` or `svmat2` help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without losing information"? Is that not losing the dataset in memory?

Comment: I took the liberty to change a bit of the wording (including the title) so it is easier to understand. You can roll the changes back if I misunderstood anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Stata variable names can usually start with an underscore `_`, **[U] 11.3 Naming conventions** explains that `_cons` is a reserved name, and they can't be used as variable names.

I think you want this:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
str3 iso3 var1 var2 var3
GBR    10 13 15
USA    9 7 4
FRA    8 8 7
BEL    3 4 5
end

local vars var2 var3
reg var1 var2 var3

matrix A = r(table)

// get original row names of matrix (and row count)
local rownames : rowfullnames A
local c : word count `rownames'

// get original column names of matrix and substitute out _cons
local names : colfullnames A
local newnames : subinstr local names "_cons" "cons", word

// rename columns of matrix
matrix colnames A = `newnames'

// convert to dataset
clear
svmat A, names(col)

// add matrix row names to dataset
gen rownames = ""
forvalues i = 1/`c' {
    replace rownames = "`:word `i' of `rownames''" in `i'
}

// check
order rownames
list, sep(0)
```

*Extended macro functions* are used. See `help extended_fcn` if you're not familiar with them.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226194/stata-combining-coefficients-standard-errors-from-several-regressions-in-a-sing/32235640#32235640), which is very similar, and suggests `postfile` and `statsby`.

Finally, check `ssc describe estout`, if your goal is to output regression tables.